# css/javascript: number above border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to display a small number (left top border) above a border around an element?

basically I am looking for a way to highlight elements and identify them with a number.

UPDATE:

Basically the elements highlight on mouseover by having border property defined. on mouseout, border is transparent (disappears).

what I'd like to do is how to display a number outside of the border highlight selected?

Solution I just thought about is using a custom generated numbered image border and just use border-image dynamically

Comment: Display it in a `div` that is positioned relative to the top left of the element?

Comment: Wrap them with a div and put your number in the div as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to insert this number dynamically for any element without having to worry about relatives and absolutes [here is a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EJD3R/).

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

---

```
#box{
    background:red;
    height:140px;
    width:250px;
    margin:30px;
}

.number{
    background:#ccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

---

```
// Create an span element that will have the number
var number          = $("<span />").text("5").addClass("number");
// Set the number width and height
var numberWidth     = 10;
var numberHeight    = 10;

// Get the target element
var element         = $("#box");
// Get width, height and position
var elementWidth    = element.width();

// These two are only necesary if you want to position
// the number in a different corner (e.g bottom, right)
var elementHeight   = element.height();
var elementPosition = element.offset();

// Apply css to the number element
// Position is based on the target element position
number.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left:     elementPosition.left - numberWidth,
    top:      elementPosition.top  - numberHeight,
    width:    numberWidth,
    height:   numberHeight
});

// Insert the number to the body
number.appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "highlight"? Mouseover? You can provision for such visual effects by first wrapping your element with another `div` which will hold your number. And example:

```
<style>

    .container:hover .label {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .label {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .content {
        margin: 1px;
        border: none;
    }

    .content:hover {
        margin: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="label">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        My Element
    </div>
</div>
```

Edited to only display border on mouse over.

Answer (score 1):

If the identification numbers are constant and you don't want to include them in the markup as content, you can include them as attribute values and use :before pseudo-elements:

CSS:

```
p { position : relative }
p:hover:before {
  content : attr(title);
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : -1em
}
```

HTML:

```
<p title="1">blah blah</p>
<p title="2">blah blah</p>
<p title="3">blah blah</p>
```

If the identification numbers can be generated each time the page is rendered, you can use an automatic counter instead:

CSS:

```
p {
  position : relative;
  counter-increment : idnum
}
p:hover:before {
  content : counter(idnum);
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : -1em
}
```

See here for more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html